# Отсутствие итерации цикла for

Tags: java

Есть массив `int`ов и `int`, с которым мы сравниваем значения массива. Если одно из значений массива меньше одного их элементов, то печатаем сообщение с номером элемента. Если нет, то печатаем, что все нормально. IDEA подсказывает, что `for statement does not loop`, но я не могу понять, в чем проблема. Импорты и декларация класса/метода main корректны.

```
 int[] arr = new int[] {300,205,400,400,402};
 int max = 210;

    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= max ) {
            System.out.println("Violation on element " + (j + 1));
            break;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("No violation");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: оператор break разрывает цикл
просто убери break в двух случаях и все будет ок, удачи в изучении java!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Вашем коде цикл *в любом случае* прерывается внутри первой итерации. Об этом и подсказка.

Вот так выводится номер первого элемента, не превышающего `max`:

```
int index = -1;
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] <= max) {
        index = j;
        break;
    }
}
if (index == -1)
    System.out.println("No violation");
else
    System.out.println("Violation on element " + (index + 1));
```

А так - номера всех таких элементов:

```
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[j] <= max) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Violation on element " + (j + 1));
    }
}
if (count == 0)
    System.out.println("No violation");
```